# Iterate thru all RadComboBox and run stored procedure for each one in a form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I have a form with  radcomoboxes i need to fill them with some data on page load i do this with a store procedure no problem.

But I don't want to have to do it one by one since there are 31 o those i try something like these but cant get the for each to enter when it runs in to a radcombobox.

page load method

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        GetName()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the method that i try to use to run thru all controls and when it finds a radcombobox call a method but it never does

```
Private Sub GetName()
    Dim cControl As Control
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is RadComboBox) Then
            'this line of code never executes
            FillComentario(cControl)
        End If
    Next cControl
End Sub
```

This method is intended to receive the ID of the radcombobox and execute the SP

```
Public Sub FillComentario(ByVal comentario As RadComboBox)
    lector = objBd.GetComentario()
    While lector.Read
        crearRcmb_Item(comentario, lector(0), lector(0))
    End While
End Sub
```

My store procedure that return a list o values for the combo box

```
Public Function GetComentario() As SqlDataReader
    Return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(conexion, Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SP_GetComentario")
End Function
```

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Do you want the controls name or what. This confuses me, "but cant get the for each to enter when it runs in to a radcombobox." What do you mean by this?

Comment: Also it's bad practice to have the same name as methods in your arguments, this will and can cause problems.

Comment: From what I see you have a method, a function and your also passing these names as an argument in, this can cause problems.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR i made the changes that you suggested. hopfully you can help me